# Dramatiq: Getting the worker name within the actor function

Tags: dramatiq

Does Dramatiq offer a way to get some sort of a human-readable name of the worker within the `@dramatiq.actor` function? I would use this to separate log lines from different works.

For example, something like `dramatiq-process-1-worker-3`.

```
@dramatiq.actor(broker=redis_broker, store_results=True, result_ttl=10*1000)
def ping():
     # Log worker name here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can use the `CurrentMessage` middllware

```py
from dramatiq.middleware import CurrentMessage

@dramatiq.actor(broker=redis_broker, store_results=True, result_ttl=10*1000)
def ping():
    msg = CurrentMessage.get_current_message()
    print(msg.actor_name)
```